# Chromium incomplete page rendering

Tags: 22.04, chromium

My Chromium suddenly stopped rendering pages, even locally produced pages like `chrome://settings/help` on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
apt reports the version as:

```
chromium-browser-l10n/jammy-updates,jammy-updates 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1 all
chromium-browser/jammy-updates 1:85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu2.22.04.1 amd64
```

The page is mostly white, with the only graphics being the Chromium pinwheel. The content seems to be there -- when I mouse over the page, the cursor changes to the finger icon, and I see the URLs displayed at the very bottom of the window. If I click and drag, lines appear to be highlighted, but no characters are visible.
One guess is that the default CSS style is gorped, but I have no clue how to reset the style since I can't see the content of the help and settings pages.

Meanwhile, Firefox runs just fine (as I am writing this with Firefox).

Any ideas?

Thanks.